# Работа с датой в SQL, PHP

Tags: php, sql

Мне нужно сделать запрос к базе, подскажите, какой из двух видов запросов будет оптимальней.

1) Генерируем дату в php и просто передаём её в sql (тип поля `date_end` timestamp)

```
<?php
mysql_query("SELECT*FROM WHERE ".time()." <= `date_end`"); 
?>
```

2) Воспользуемся встроенной функцией

```
<?php
mysql_query("SELECT*FROM WHERE NOW()<=`date_end`"); 
?>
```

И хотелось бы узнать, в каком формате в базе лучше хранить дату в datetime или timestamp

Answer (score 2):

[`time()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php) выдает время в секундах с начала юникс эпохи, соответстсвенно не факт, что даже два подряд идущие вызова функции time дадут один и тот же результат, поэтому говорить о кэшировании запросов (как предложил [@draev](/users/2572/draev)) бессмысленно, если только вы результат `time()` не зафиксируете (сохраните в переменную) в начале скрипта и не будете его везде использовать.

Лично мое имхо - использовать подстановку данных в SQL запрос только там где она реально необходима, поэтому во всех проектах стараюсь использовать нативные mysql средства работы с датами и временем. К тому же в последствии их легче проверять вне php и править данные в таблице вручную (формат данных поля в таблице соответствует формату возвращаемому стандартной mysql функцией).

Answer (score 1):

1. этот вариант будет закэширован, скорость выборки будет больше
2. mysql не кэширует запросы в которых используются функции, относящиеся к текущему времени (NOW(), CURDATE() и др.)

Дату можно хранить в любом удобном для вас формате.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Но я так понимаю от кэширования в первом запросе толку не будет, так как если мы отправим этот запрос в другое время, то time() будет иным и кэш бесполезен?

Answer (score 0):

Насчет выбора формата почитайте [здесь (на английском)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

Вкратце:
Если Вам надо хранить дату/время сообщений на форуме - можете выбирать "по вкусу"
Если же Вам надо записывать даты исторических событий, TIMESTAMP не поможет (от '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC до '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC), выбирайте DATETIME - он позволяет фиксировать дату/время в диапазоне от '1000-01-01 00:00:00' до '9999-12-31 23:59:59'

Помимо диапазонов, TIMESTAMP имеет еще одно отличие - он "автообновляется в соответствии с временной зоной клиента" - то есть, если в Москве сообщение было помечено как написанное в 3 часа, в Лондоне клиент увидит, что оно было написано в 0 часов по Гринвичу...

Comment: Для того чтобы TIMESTAMP выдался в другом часовом поясе, этот пояснадо указать перед выборкой данных из таблице. Также вы еще забыли про одно отличие - Если в таблице есть поле TIMESTAMP, то при UPDATE строки данное поле будет выставлено в текущее время обновления. Если у вас в таблице несколько TIMESTAMP'ов то обновлен будет только первый из них. Вообщем если вы обновляете данные то учитывайте этот факт о TIMESTAMP. При INSERT'e в таблицу с TIMESTAMP'ом если его не задать явно, то он будет выставлен в текущую дату и время.